# Getting the Error - ASL CLI is not functional - unknown option '-l'

Tags: visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use VC.Code on Windows to work on Alexa skills.

I've installed:

- nodejs
- List item
- ASK CLI

Extension added to VSCode:

- Alexa Skills Kit (ASK) Toolkit
- AWS Toolkit

When I run ASK CLI from the cmd window it seems fine.

However, when I try use most commands from VSCode Command Pallete

e.g.

ASK: Create a skill from a template'

or

'ASK: Clone a skill'

I get an error, as it appears the first thing the the command issues is "ask init -l"

which results in:

error: unknown option '-l'

Sure enough typing ask init -l into the cmd window causes the same error.

- Why are the ASk commands in VSCode using an incorrect parameter?
- Is it incorrect?
- How do I make the commands work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that currently the VSCode ASK extension only works with ASK CLI v1.x.

ASK CLI v2 was released mid-April 2020 and included [breaking changes](https://github.com/alexa/ask-toolkit-for-vscode/issues/15#issuecomment-617856651) making it incompatible with the VSCode ASK extension.

If you wanted to use the VSCode ASK extension, you could install the last release of ASK CLI v1 by running:

`npm i ask-cli@^1.0.0`